# Tomcat7 -Error parsing HTTP request header

Tags: ssl, tomcat7, wildcard

I am first time trying to convert my application run in http to https using wildcard certificate in tomcat7.i have done installation steps for SSL and wildcard certificate in tomcat7 and changed the config in server.xml like below,

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<Server port="8006" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">

 <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JasperListener" />
  <!-- Prevent memory leaks due to use of particular java/javax APIs-->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener" />

 <GlobalNamingResources>
    <!-- Editable user database that can also be used by
         UserDatabaseRealm to authenticate users
    -->
    <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
              type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
              description="User database that can be updated and saved"
              factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
              pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
  </GlobalNamingResources>

  <Connector port="8106" protocol="HTTP/1.1"  maxHttpHeaderSize="1048576"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               URIEncoding="UTF-8"
               redirectPort="8443" />


 <Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
               maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
               clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />
    -->

        <Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
          maxHttpHeaderSize="1048576" maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
           clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"
           keystoreFile="conf/mydomain.keystore"
           keystorePass="pswd"
           keyPass="pswd" />
```

and i have added the web.xml in my application like below,

```
<security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>securedapp</web-resource-name>
            <http-method>GET</http-method>
            <http-method>POST</http-method>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <user-data-constraint>
            <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
        </user-data-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
```

but when i access my URL https://myIP:8106 then i can not access my port through https: it gives,

```
Dec 07, 2015 9:09:22 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor process
INFO: Error parsing HTTP request header
 Note: further occurrences of HTTP header parsing errors will be logged at DEBUG level.
Dec 07, 2015 9:09:22 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor process
INFO: Error parsing HTTP request header
 Note: further occurrences of HTTP header parsing errors will be logged at DEBUG level.
```

but if i give https://myIP:8443/ then it works.I must need to run my applicaion using the 8106 because i am running my application in rest calls.

where am i doing mistake?

Comment: You've configured an http (nonsecure) connector on 8106 and an https (ssl) connector on 8443. When you use https on 8443 it works. When you try to use https on 8106 it doesn't work, because 8106 isn't https. If you want https on 8106, put the (or a) https connector on 8106, and remove the http connector on 8106 because you can't have two protocols on one port.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 ya you are right. Thank you